# Microsoft Visio choose few table entities and observe relationships

Tags: visio

I am using Microsoft Visio 2007.
I have to optimize some queries in a database with about two hundred tables.
I know the affected tables from the query and can I choose only those tables and observe the relationships among them using visio?

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find the answer for this question.
But, since I was using PostgreSQL with pgAdminIII, I could derive a database ER diagram using pgAdminIII.
Using this diagram I could select tables where I can see the relationships of that table.
For more information, anybody can follow [this link](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/)